# Errors when Compiling Mono on Windows via Cygwin

Tags: build, mono, makefile, cygwin, autogen

I follow this tutorial: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/compiling-mono/windows/

I have downloaded the Mono source code from GitHub (as of today).

My autogen command line is as follows:

```
sh autogen.sh --host=i686-pc-mingw32
```

I've got two autogen warnings, no errors (see below). Then I run `make` and I'm getting errors:

```
Makefile:2463: recipe for target 'libmonoruntime_la-threadpool.lo' failed
make[3]: *** [libmonoruntime_la-threadpool.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/projects/mono/mono/mono/metadata'
Makefile:436: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/projects/mono/mono/mono'
Makefile:520: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/projects/mono/mono'
Makefile:447: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have no idea how to solve this error. The `libmonoruntime_la-threadpool.lo` contains:

```
# libmonoruntime_la-assembly.lo - a libtool object file
# Generated by doltcompile, not libtool
pic_object='.libs/libmonoruntime_la-assembly.o'
non_pic_object='libmonoruntime_la-assembly.o'
```

I have checked and both the mentioned files `libmonoruntime_la-assembly.o` exist.

Complete `make` output can be found here: http://pastebin.com/WyytVHXq

I also don't know if these errors depend on the autogen warnings. For completeness, the warnings are:

```
mono/unit-tests/Makefile.am:7: warning: variable 'TEST_LDFLAGS' is defined but no program or
mono/unit-tests/Makefile.am:7: library has 'TEST' as canonical name (possible typo)

/cygdrive/c/projects/mono/mono/libgc/missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option
Try `/cygdrive/c/projects/mono/mono/libgc/missing --help' for more information
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
```

As for the second warning, I was looking for newer libgc `missing` script but couldn't find it.

Comment: I believe the actual error is on line 969 "../../mono/metadata/threadpool-internals.h:11:2: error: unknown type name 'mono_mutex_t'".

Comment: This issue was fixed by this [commit](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/0b2a537abf74216b02657b2992d6c916464a742d#diff-cc5f61607afcbf260e96ed7a049b62ee).

Comment: Just as a matter of interest, why compile Mono at all on Windows? Licensing?